# Trying to parse logfile based on start and end time

Tags: bash, sed, awk, logfile

I am trying to parse large zipped logfile and would like to collect all matching parameters within a certain time range:

Wed Nov  3 09:27:20 2010 : remote IP address 209.151.64.18
Wed Nov  3 11:57:22 2010 : secondary DNS address 204.117.214.10

I am able to grep other parameter using the line below:
gzcat  jfk-gw10-asr1.20100408.log.gz | egrep gabriel|98.126.209.144\|13.244.137.58\|16.151.65.121

I have been unable to parse for the start time and/or end time.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the log file is chronologically sorted you could do e.g.:

```
gzcat jfk-gw10-asr1.20100408.log.gz | sed -n '/Nov 3 09:/,/Nov 3 11:/p'
```

to get log entries between 09:00:00 and 11:59:59 on Nov, 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

you can access space separated field using awk:

```
cat you_file_name | awk '/ / { print $1;}'
```

Use $[n] to print the desired field.